# How to run 2 servers as separate processes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have 2 services and each has a controller.

```
@Service
public class Service1
{
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller1
{
}
```

...

```
@Service
public class Service2
{
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller2
{
}
```

I would like to run each service or controller in their own process. How can I do this without creating two apps?

This is similar to what I want, see image below:
[image]

Comment: Two different microservices?

Comment: Yeah that would be perfect. As long as they keep running so that I can continue doing rest calls.

Comment: Then you need two separate apps, but I don't understand where's the problem? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I don't want to have two apps.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with two separate processes (but not wanting to have two apps)?

Comment: @J_Strauton Clarification question: From your point of view, what's the difference between an app and a process?

Comment: @Sebastian some programs will create separate processes for their own needs. Is this not possible in spring-boot?

Comment: @entpnerd I don't want to have two code bases. I want to launch the app then it launches two processes.

Comment: You could create your own process from java by eg. using the [Runtime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). But I´m most certain that´s not what you want. So we need to know what you try to achieve to help you.

Comment: @Sebastian that wouldn't do it. I want to have these two processes not share the same space (heap, etc.). I don't want to get into too many details because it will just be noise. The simplest example I can give is that in Android we can launch a Service and have it run in its own process.

Comment: `Runtime.exec(...)` will start a new process. As per defenition a new process has it´s own memspace. That´s  the only way to start a new process from Java.

Comment: @Sebastian and Spring Boot doesn't have any support for that? How could I use `Runtime.exec` and force `Service1` to only run on that process?

Comment: I don't really see the point of creating 2 processes. If you want to scale your app, you can simply use microservices architecture. In a proper microservices architecture you can create multiple application (services) with certain responsibilities and scale them. You don't really need to duplicate the codebase - just split it wisely.

Comment: @ArthurGurov so each service would be its own project?

Comment: Spring-boot mvc applications run inside on embedded server or, i f you chose it so, deployed on a different server. I'm guessing you are most likely using the embedded server approach because it's more convenient  By running your app, you will see the process of the embedded server. Spring is multi threaded by nature, but in general you don't have to worry about this. If you want to do load-balancing by yourself, you probably should look inside micro-service architecture.

Comment: Basically, yes. However, it's not necessary - you can create multiple sub-modules in Maven or Gradle and build them as a separate app (service). You can also create an additional sub-module with common shared code (business model classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the attached components diagram, I would suggest looking into microservices architecture. You will be able to separate responsibilities by domains (movie, customer, review) and even build separate access rules (e.g. anonymous access for movies catalog and secured access to customer data). Each data storage (DB1, DB2, etc.) will be linked to the responsible service only. In addition, you will be able to scale exactly the necessary services depending on usage e.g. 5 movie services, 2 customer data services, and 3 review services.

Gradle or Maven will easily allow you to build a big project with multiple sub-modules. Some of your modules will be application modules and some of them will be shared modules (models, utils, etc.).

In addition, I would recommend to set up a separate repo for each project in order to simplify change management and review - it will be very helpful on a big scale.

**Example Gradle structure:**

Root module

- models
- utils
- movie service
- customer service
- review service

Each service sub-module will contain its own @SpringBootApplication with controllers, services and repositories. Of course, you will need to add Spring Boot Gradle plugin to each service sub-module.

**Update:**
Going forward, it would be wise to add Docker configuration to each service sub-module and run each application as a Docker container. Docker will significantly simplify the development.

Comment: How can gradle help me build these modules as separate apps? I can't use multiple repos, because of some weird management decision. If I make a module for each service what do I do so that when I run this code each module becomes its own app?

Comment: An example structure and some explanation have been added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It will be ambiguous if you can do such a thing.
For example when you call localhost:8080/app -> which controller should response ? Maybe you need to implement a dispatcher with some criteria which of the controllers should be invoked. I don't understand what is the benefit of such separation. You can divide your app into libraries and add them as dependencies.